# How to process the query under conditions using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to clean an Excel dataset. The dataset gets updated on a regular basis, therefore I created a 'Flag' column which marks an entry as either 'Feasible' or 'Not Feasible'. If an entry is marked as 'Not Feasible' it has not been processed yet.

In my example, I only want to execute the transformations on entries with the 'Not Feasible' flag.

**Input Data :**

```
name  Joining_Date      age   Contact    col4   col5  col6  flag

NKJ    4/26/2021        48!   96754789   8886H  AHBZ        Not feasible
Tom    26.4.2021        27    98468300   ^686H  ANKZ        feasible
Mike   2/27/2021        28@   78915359   3256H  AK9Z        Not feasible
NKJ    27.2.2021        48!   96754789   8886H  AHBZ        Not feasible
Adam   2/14/2021        18#   78915899   3256H  AK7Z        Not feasible
Steve  3/11/2021        23@   7891HI59   3256H  AK5Z        feasible
JKN    2/12/2021        35    96451188   3566H  NK4Z        Not feasible
```

**Expected Output**

```
name  Joining_Date      age   Contact    col4   col5  col6  flag

NKJ    2021-4-26        48    96754789   8886H  AHBZ        feasible
Tom    26.4.2021        27    98468300   ^686H  ANKZ        feasible
Mike   2021-2-27        28    78915359   3256H  AK9Z        feasible
NKJ    2021-2-27        48    96754789   8886H  AHBZ        feasible
Adam   2021-2-14        18    78915899   3256H  AK7Z        feasible
Steve  3/11/2021        23@   7891HI59   3256H  AK5Z        feasible
JKN    2021-2-12        35    96451188   3566H  NK4Z        feasible
```

In the end before writing the data frame to Excel, I have been looking to concat both data (data processed under condition + unprocessed data)

Code I have been using so far:

```
if flag == 'Not feasible':
  df['Joining_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Joining_Date'], errors='coerce')
  df['Joining_Date'] = df['Joining_Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  df['age'] = df['age'].replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
  df[['col4','col5']] = df[['col4','col5']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace('\W',''))
  df['contact'] = df['contact'].replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
  df['flag'] = "feasible"
```

**Above Script gives the following error:**

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Also Tried Using :

```py
    df1 = df.loc[df['flag'] != 'Not feasible']      
    df = df.loc[df['flag'] == 'Not feasible'].copy()
    
    # Run your cleaning codes with original syntax   
    df['Joining_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Joining_Date'], errors='coerce')
    df['Joining_Date'] = df['Joining_Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    df['age'] = df['age'].replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
    df[['col4','col5']] = df[['col4','col5']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace('\W',''))
    df['Contact'] = df['Contact'].replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
    df['flag'] = "feasible"
    
    df = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_index() 
    print(df.head())
```

**Error:**

In the above script the date format for df1['Joining_Date'] column is also changed, For Eg. "26.4.2021" to "2021-4-26"

Comment: You can use `.copy()` also for creating  `df1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try also using `.copy()` for creating `df1` if you found subsequent codes changed also the values of contents in `df1`.

```
df1 = df.loc[df['flag'] != 'Not feasible'].copy()
```

By defining `df1` and `df` as 2 separate copies, they should not affect each others by the middle part of cleaning scripts.

Comment: by making the change as suggested above now after processing getting the format like "2021-4-26 00:00:00"

Comment: @NKJ  Maybe it is owing to `pd.concat()` aligned different formats when concatenating the rows.   Anyway, it's a good standard format to use especially when you have different styles of date fields.  Without standardizing to a unified format, your date will will be confusing and can't determine the actual dates (e.g. whether 5/6/2021 is May 6 or June 5 in 2021.

Comment: @Seabean- Is there any method to avoid change in dateformat for df1 dataframe.

Comment: @NKJ  Probably one column in datetime64 format can't have mixed formats.  If you absolutely need to retain original format, probably you have to maintain the field as string rather than datetime format then.  You can add a new column of string dates side by side with the standard date field in ISO format.